# How to subtract a seperate count from one grouping

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres query like this

```
select application.status as status, count(*) as "current_month" from application
where to_char(application.created, 'mon') = to_char('now'::timestamp - '1 month'::interval, 'mon') 
    and date_part('year',application.created) = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) 
    and application.job_status != 'expired'
group by application.status
```

it returns the table below that has the number of applications grouped by status for the current month. However I want to subtract a total count of a seperate but related query from the internal review number only. I want to count the number of rows with *type* = abc within the same table and for the same date range and then subtract that amount from the internal review number (Type is a seperate field). Current_month_desired is how it should look.

| status | current_month | current_month_desired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fail | 22 | 22 |
| internal_review | 95 | 22 |
| pass | 146 | 146 |

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED: but maybe...

The intent here is to use an analytic and case expression to conditionally sum.  This way, the subtraction is not needed in the first place as you are only "counting" the values needed.

```
SELECT application.status as status
     , sum(case when type = 'abc' 
                 and application.status ='internal_review' then 0 
            else 1 end) over (partition by application.status)) as 
      "current_month" 
 FROM application
WHERE to_char(application.created, 'mon') = to_char('now'::timestamp - '1 month'::interval, 'mon') 
  and date_part('year',application.created) = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) 
  and application.job_status != 'expired'
GROUP BY application.status
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately this didn't work, I think due to the fact that im not looking to just remove the cases where an application has status internal_review and also has type 'abc', but to remove the total of all cases with type 'abc' from the total of all cases with statuses of internal_review, if that makes sense.

Comment: to clarify more its not that there are 73 cases of internal review with type 'abc' that need to be filtered out, there are 73 cases of type 'abc in the whole table, across both pass, fail & internal review applications that need to specifically be subtracted from the total of internal review applications